# Qt unit testing output string length cut-off

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qunit

I am currently running Qt unit tests that compare long JSON strings. Upon failure, the Qt output shows the expected and actual values of the strings. However, they are being truncated after a certain number of characters. Is there any way to have Qt display the entire contents of the strings?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible.

See the definition of Qt Testlib's compare function: http://code.woboq.org/data/symbol.html?root=../qt5/&ref=_ZN11QTestResult7compareEbPKcPcS2_S1_S1_S1_i

The max message length is hard-coded, 1024 chars. This also truncates the actual/expected values.

Answer (score 0):

The max length can't be fixed. Segmentation of string into array and checking would serve. Split string to arrays of limited size.